# Python regex works without optional group, but breaks with optional group

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

Given an input:

```
line = " say hi /* comment"
```

and a regex:

```
regex = re.compile(r'\s*(?P<command>.*?)/[/*]')
result = regex.search(line)
print(result.group('command'))
```

This will successfully print `say hi`.

However, switching the last part to an optional group:

```
regex = re.compile(r'\s*(?P<command>.*?)(/[/*])?')
```

now doesn't print anything.  It's not the regex doesn't match it at all, because `result` isn't `None`.

Why is it that it works when the regex is not optional, but stops working when it is optional, and how would I go about solving it?

Comment: `\s*` can match the leading space, and then `.*?` (your 'command' group) can match an empty string.  Generally speaking, a non-greedy match has to have *something* non-optional following it, or it will happily match nothing at all.

Answer (score 1):

`regex.search()` will find first match substring. You can use `regex.findall()` in this case.

`regex.search()` docs said:

> If there is more than one match, only the first occurrence of the match will be returned

Because `/[/*]` optional, it has no constraint to match `/` character. So it can even match first space, it can match any part.

You can check this regular expression online in [regex101](https://regex101.com/). you can find its process and results.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is not the answer you are looking for, but it may help:

```
regex = re.compile(r'\s*(?P<command>.*?)/[/*](?P<optional>.*)')
result = regex.search(line)
print(result.group('command','optional'))
```

output:

```
('say hi ', ' comment')
```

For details click [here](https://regex101.com/r/rymaHU/1)

Answer (score 0):

In the above example, `?P<command>.*?` use the non-greedy qualifiers *?, +?, ??, or {m,n}?, which match as little text as possible. See [Greedy versus Non-Greedy](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#greedy-versus-non-greedy) for more details

And since the `(/[/*])?` is optional, the **command** group could be match nothing.

If you want to regex a line without comment, use the following

```
\s*(?P<command>.*?)(?:/[/*]|$)
```

to match

```
" say hi /* comment"
" say hi ..."
```